# Getting an uncaught type error in JS but confused on why

Tags: javascript, while-loop, typeerror

I am currently practicing while loops and then turning loops into recursion below is an example of code that produces the result but I am unsure why I am getting a type error:

```
const frenchie = {
    name: "Lokys",
    friend: {
        name: "Benken",
        friend: {
            name: "Weller"
        }
    }
}

let currentFrench = frenchie
while(currentFrench !== null){
    console.log(currentFrench.name)
    currentFrench = currentFrench.friend
    
}
```

Above code will produce the output I want in regards to the name but the error message I see is:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
at script.js:13:31**

However, if I change the code to this:

```
const frenchie = {
    name: "Lokys",
    friend: {
        name: "Benken",
        friend: {
            name: "Weller"
        }
    }
}

let currentFrench = frenchie
while(currentFrench != null){
    console.log(currentFrench.name)
    currentFrench = currentFrench.friend
    
}
```

It produces the same result but with no type error. I THOUGHT `!==` using a strict bang operator (i think this is the right term I am still learning) like this would be the best route. Similar to house I try to use `const` vs `let` when it makes sense to not produce side effects or `==` vs `===`

Comment: Strict inequality means that the `undefined` you get is ***not*** equal to `null`, thus the code proceeds with `currentFrench = undefined`. Which then throws an error. However, `undefined` and `null` are loosely equal thus for `currentFrench = undefined` the check `currentFrench != null` is `false`.

Comment: `while` loop is rarely a good way to iterate an object, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: @Teemu - A `while` loop seems absolutely fine here to me (as far as we can tell from the question -- that is, assuming an unknown number of layers).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, I said "_rarely_". These questions tend to evolve, and when OP finally responses, we'll probably find a question which will need recursive approach (not that it couldn't be built on `while` loops too), unless poor Weller has no friends at all.

Comment: @Teemu - :-) Yeah, recursion is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

The innermost `friend` object has no `friend` property, so accessing it gives you `undefined`. But you're testing for `null`, not `undefiend`. With `===` and `!==`, `null` and `undefined` are distinct. With `==` and `!=`, they're treated as though they were the same.

In this particular case, since you're expecting `currentFrench` to be either an *object* or `undefined`, the idiomatic way to write it would be simply `while (currentFrench)`. But you could use `!= null` or (if it will never be `null`) `!== undefined` if you like.

---

> I THOUGHT !== using a strict bang operator (i think this is the right term I am still learning)

It's the "[strict inequality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality)."

Answer (score 1):

#### It is because you are advancing to a `.friend` that doesn't exist

On the final step, you are expecting this to yield `undefined`:

```
currentFrench = currentFrench.friend
```

That happens, but then the while criterion is not met: currentFrency (undefined) really is *not* exactly equal to `null`, so the `while` continues, and you get an error when you try to advance again into the non-existent friend of the already non-existent person.

#### I suggest you change the `while` to:

```
 while (currentFrench)
```

That would get the concept across to the reader as well.

#### In principle you could use `while (currentFrench !== undefined)`

However, doing so always makes me laugh because it reminds me that you can create a variable called undefined and set it to something, but can't actually read it back.

[image]

Comment: "*someone could cheekily create a variable called undefined to mess up your life.*" not easily possible nowadays. Attempting to overwrite the global `undefined` *mostly* leads to an error. You can, however, shadow it: `fn = (undefined) => console.log(typeof undefined); fn("hello");`

Comment: THANK YOU, this makes total sense. I just went through control flow lessons and trying to be very detailed in what I am writing to connect the parts on JS but this makes so much sense.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't realise it had changed! I've added what actually happens on Chrome currently. Replaces one hilarious situation with another.